Armature Symmetrize not working properly
To summarize, whenever I attempt to use the Symmetrize operation on my Armature, it symmetrizes BACKWARDS on my model rather than right/left, as if my arm and leg bones are the STRUCTURE of the model rather than the spine. No attempts to solve this have resolved it so far.


Hi Fuery, can you tell us what those attempts are, before we start suggesting the same ones? :)

The Symmetrize operation will happen on the X axis of your armature, your armature is probably not correctly oriented, to fix that activate the Transform Affect Only Origins option and rotate its origin 90° (or -90°) on Z, and deactivate the option:

